# PHP Strange behaviour with recursive arrays

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, reference

```php
$array = array();
$array[ 'recursive' ] =& $array;

$array[ 'foo' ] = $array;
```

`'foo'` was assigned by value to `$array`, which should copy `$array`, which did not have a `'foo'` key at the time, so I expect the situation to now be something like:

```
$array = array(
    'recursive' => &$array,
    'foo'       => array(
        'recursive' => &$array
    ),
)
```

But if I now do:

```
var_dump( isset( $array[ 'foo' ][ 'foo' ][ 'foo' ] ) );
```

I get:

```
bool(true)
```

I don't understand why this is.

If I create an intermediate variable for the assignment of `'foo'`, like this:

```php
$array = array();
$array[ 'recursive' ] =& $array;

$blah = $array;
$array[ 'foo' ] = $blah;

var_dump( isset( $array[ 'foo' ][ 'foo' ][ 'foo' ] ) );
```

I get:

```
bool(false)
```

I understand why the `'recursive'` key would be infinitely deep, because that was assigned by reference, but why the `'foo'` key, which was assigned by value? How can creating an intermediate variable change behaviour for things handled by value?

Comment: It probably has something to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528280/why-does-reference-assigning-an-arrays-element-modify-the-array/17528610#17528610, see if you can figure it out. It's too late for me right now. :)

Comment: I tried to imagine what the symbol tables would look like as the code executes, as per the answer you linked to, but I only arrive at the behaviour I expected, not the behaviour I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do $array['foo'] = $array, the interpreter first adds the 'foo' index to the $array value, then puts that newly updated array inside $array['foo'].

When you use an intermediate $blah, you've stored an unmodified copy of $array from before the 'foo' key was created. The intermediate doesn't change the behavior, it stores a copy of the value at the moment in time that the intermediate is created, just as it should.

Comment: Then why does `$a = array(); $a['foo'] = $a;` not produce recursion?

Comment: @Jesse just wanted to ask the same :). I think that it's wrong statement. We need to look in PHP sources.